# D3 append a line or rect to fill pie chart values

Tags: d3.js, svg

using d3 v5.15.0

I'm building a pie chart, in which I want to use a line or rectangle to fill in the value, (or flatten the arch to appear this way maybe?). Currently I'm able to use an arc to fill it in.

Removed images.

```js
import * as d3 from "d3";

const startAngle = (-40 * Math.PI) / 180;
const endAngle = (-40 * Math.PI) / 180 + 2 * Math.PI;
const width = 500;
const height = Math.min(width, 500);

function drawBenefitsValues(svg, data, startArc) {
  const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  const degreesToRadians = degrees => degrees * 0.0174533;
  const innerFactor = startArc;
  const outerFactor = value => innerFactor + value * 0.0509;
  const slice = degreesToRadians(30);

  // TODO - Is there a way to draw the path with a calculated arc and avoid the forEach?
  data.forEach((ele, idx) => {
    const id = `gBenefits${idx}`;
    const color =
      ele.benefits > 4.75
        ? "#999A57"
        : ele.benefits > 3.33
        ? "#E2B465"
        : ele.benefits > 2
        ? "#E2B465"
        : "#D3665D";
    const angleBegins = startAngle + idx * slice;
    const gridPie = d3
      .pie()
      .startAngle(angleBegins + 0.05)
      .endAngle(angleBegins + slice)
      .padAngle(0.05)
      .sort(null)
      .value(1);

    const arc = d3
      .arc()
      .innerRadius(radius * innerFactor + 1)
      .outerRadius(radius * outerFactor(ele.benefits))
      .padRadius(radius * 2.5)

    svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("id", id)
      .selectAll(`#${id}`)
      .data(gridPie([ele]))
      .join("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("class", "benefits")
      .attr("fill", color);
  });
}
```

Comment: What d3 version are you using and could we get some sample data to play with?

Comment: Hi @coola I added a code sandbox of what I'm working with. The code code for the wheel can be found in wheel.js under the drawBenefitsValues function and the data can be found in index.js.

Comment: Hi Carlos. So I am not able to match the screenshots to the codesandbox. Could you provide the whole picture and highlight the part you want changed and what it should look like?

Comment: hi #@Coola I just added the bigger image, the rest should look about the same as what I have in the code sandbox except for the middle spokes. Currently the values are following the arch path making angled rectangles when they receive the values but I'm trying to make them to be more like normal rectangles as seen in the last 2 images.

Comment: I see, so you could calculate the arc, get the coordinates and then try to get the mid point of the arc. After that you can create a path from one point to the other? Would that logic work? Have you tried that?

Comment: hmm, that sounds right but I'm not exactly sure how to do that in d3. Still learning how to use it and had some help putting this together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

friend helped me come up with a sort of hacky solution. Basically I set the the start and endAngles of the arc to be the same. This will of course cause the element to disappear because there is no more arch, just a straight line. I then added a stroke along with a stroke width to create a sort of rectangle out of the arch.

```
const arc = d3
      .arc()
      .innerRadius(radius * outerFactor(ele.overuses))
      .startAngle(d => d.startAngle)
      .outerRadius(radius * innerFactor)
      .endAngle(d => d.startAngle);

svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("id", id)
      .selectAll(`#${id}`)
      .data(gridPie([ele]))
      .join("path")
      .attr("class", "benefits")
      .attr("fill", color)
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("stroke-width", "18")
      .attr("stroke", color);
```